# Get all tickers for Alpha Vantage

Tags: quantitative-finance, alpha-vantage

I want to build a database of some 20,000 stocks and would like to use the AlphaVantage API to feed it with data. The documentation can be found here: [Documentation](https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/).

As of my research in stackoverflow and the Alpha Vantage Documentation, I have only been able to find a csv file of all the current active US stocks (and ETFs) -- the following API request achieves this result even with a demo API key: https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=LISTING_STATUS&apikey=demo.

I would like, however, to obtain European stocks as well.

The Alpha Vantage Database goes much deeper than US stocks, as can be seen by looking at the search functionality in the API: https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=SYMBOL_SEARCH&keywords=tesco&apikey=demo

You can get a free API key and input the query [https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=SYMBOL_SEARCH&keywords=AMKBY&apikey={YOUR_API_KEY}](https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=SYMBOL_SEARCH&keywords=AMKBY&apikey=%7BYOUR_API_KEY%7D) for a clearer example. So my question is how do I get all of these tickers and names of the stocks in a database. I could of course do a character matching (i.e. I try all of the combinations for tickers and save the company overview for stocks I have found; this program would, however, either kill my Laptop or not finish in this century. Is there a way I am missing? Maybe these tickers have a specific logic behind them that I can replicate somehow i.e. Yahoo Finance Tickers etc? The Atlas Copco AB is however a counterexample to that thesis, as it is listed in Yahoo and Google as ATCO-A and in Alphavantage as ATLCY.

New ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: There are lists of links for symbols for many stock exchanges around the world, such as https://github.com/prediqtiv/alpha-vantage-cookbook/blob/master/symbol-lists.md.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to ask yourself what your goal is.  If you just want US stocks (including ADRs) NASDAQ can give you a list that has around 7,000 stocks: https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/screener.  This should cover most use cases.

If you are trying to look globally you are going to have issues comparing ADRs vs. stocks issued directly foreign markets.  The example you mention - Atlas Copco AB - alpha vantage is listing the ADR stock symbol ATLCY and Yahoo and Google are listing the stock symbol for trading in the Swedish market, ATCO-A.  See here: https://www.atlascopcogroup.com/en/investor-relations/atlas-copco-share/share-information.  And the reality is you can't trade Swedish stocks directly without getting a brokerage account in Sweden.

FYI I looked into this for my (primitive) symbol lookup and charting webpage that uses the NASDAQ list cited above as well as the alpha vantage API for values. https://stock-quote-server.justinmemphis.repl.co/symbol_lookup